# FreeRADIUS 3, libradcli4 and ppp compatibility

Tags: debian, pptp, freeradius, point-to-point-protocol, xl2tpd

I'm using Freeradius to authenticate VPN clients using PPTP or L2TP/IPSec (xl2tpd) and I want to do an upgrade from Debian 8 to 9 on our servers incl. upgrading version of Freeradius (2 -> 3).

Both PPTP and L2TP are using `radius.so` plugin in their ppp configuration to authenticate users against Freeradius. However this plugin is not working with freeradius client *libradcli4* and other older clients (like *libfreeradius-client2*) are deprecated in Debian 9.

New *libradcli4* has different path for config files (older `/etc/radiusclient/` vs `/etc/radcli/`), unknown attribute types, e.g. `ipv4addr` in dictionary, missing `port-id-map` file etc.

Is there any working non-deprecated radius client, newer `radius.so` plugin or proper way to get this working?

Thank you